# Trimming the end of a last element of a List

Tags: c#, list

I am trimming a chracter from the end of the last element of a List and even though it works I feel it is not the best way of doing this.

```
for (int i = lstTopicsDisplay.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (i == lstTopicsDisplay.Count-1)
    {
        string lastValue = lstTopicsDisplay[i].TrimEnd(';');
        lstTopicsDisplay[i] = lastValue;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way, such as using a Lambda expression to get the same result?

Comment: Why are you iterating the list? Can't you just update the last item?

Comment: I would keep in a way you already do this. Just avoid using a for loop, if you don't need that. No any benefit of using lambda here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 int lastPos = lstTopicsDisplay.Count - 1;
 lstTopicsDisplay[lastPos] = lstTopicsDisplay[lastPos].TrimEnd(';')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lstTopicsDisplay.Last().TrimEnd(';')
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are just changing one item in the list, you don't need the loop.

Just calculating the index for the item that you want to change, and using the rest of the code unchanged:

```
int i = lstTopicsDisplay.Count - 1;

string lastValue = lstTopicsDisplay[i].TrimEnd(';');
lstTopicsDisplay[i] = lastValue;
```

Or simply:

```
lstTopicsDisplay[lstTopicsDisplay.Count - 1] = lstTopicsDisplay[lstTopicsDisplay.Count - 1].TrimEnd(';');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string lastValue = lstTopicsDisplay.[lstTopicsDisplay.Count - 1].TrimEnd(';');
```